Screenshot of the Week #114 - Video Game Food
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 114th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Batophobia's picture from princess-peach-showtime won with 13 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-04-29, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-05-06, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Video Game Food
Post a screenshot of some of the best video game cuisine you've stumbled across!
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

I'm going to get so hungry every time I open this SOTW....

@Wondercricket probably don't want to follow Low Poly Videogame Foods on twitter (this account + the theme suggestion on our theme suggestions question inspired this weeks theme)

Ah, this is a tough one. I can't decide if I want to post a 3D game or a pixel game... Maybe I could post one now and the other for the next SOTW. Hmm...

Rimworld (and Dwarf Fortress) got some interesting food, but alas not very screenshot-worthy. Using the cooking expanded mod, my colonist are going to feast on grilled racoon with barley grain and chocolate syrup tonight. Yummy! Some racoons went nuts and charged into my spike trap/auto turrets, then some colonist found them a few days later, nearly rotting. Because frying up some random roadkill is sooo 2024.

@Amarth ASCII food would of been just fine ;)

@TimmyJim Ok some of my yaks just died in the plague, hmm. I would have to post a series of screenies but I guess that's against the rules. Maybe if I'm fine with being disqualified? I feel that the world needs to know the secrets of Rimworld cooking.

Ok not to disrupt the contest, I cooked together a Rimworld cooking/free meat tutorial here. TL;DR if it is meat, it is good to eat.

Golden Egg Galette from final-fantasy-15. Also known in real life as "buckwheat crepe", or "galette bretonne".


I see final fantasy, I upvote

For a moment I wanted to complain that you submitted a photo.

@FabianRöling Lol x) Yeah, I was surprised by the realism of the meal too when I was choosing among my 6000 screenshots of the game.

A Monster Meal for a Monster Hunter

monster-hunter-world

Is it me or that cat on the left is stealing the food?

Nonsense! That's one of the chefs! He's just watching intently to ensure his craft is being properly consumed!

I meant, "purrroperly", of course.

Cooking up a Beast-Steak in dragons-dogma-2 whilst camping out under the stars in Battahl


Seeing that steak makes me want to go to Texas Roadhouse

Some radiated Cram and InstaMash found in a derelict subway in fallout-4.  The radiation adds flavor!


Yum, canned Spam - I mean Cram.

@Clockwork Spam IRL fried in a pan to make it nice and crispy is actually really good, even if its really bad for you.

@TimmyJim wait, so someone really eats that? Sorry, I'm Italian so Spam for me is like a meme

@pinckerman I'll make it for breakfast every now and then. Its a lot like bacon honestly, especially if you get the kind that's labeled "With Real Hormel Bacon"! I  put it on my breakfast egg sandwich.

Hardcore survivors stick to deathclaw steak, I hear. Organic from free-ranging deathclaws, with only the best radioactive isotopes.

If I had the time this week, I was going to post a picture of the Mouldy Food item. Bone apple teeth!

While everyone else is talking about Insta-Mash, I'm remembering the old (and very rare) Deathclaw Omelet from Fallout: New Vegas.

@Robotnik Amateur. You know that Monster Menu has an option to enable censorship on food, right?

For April fool's 2021, I filled the spawn area of Slicedlime's minecraft-java-edition server with cake! Sadly very little of it was eaten, because I removed it a few days later.

(I also changed the subscriber count from "LIMES" to "SLIMES".)

Am I the only one who feels like the cakes look like Moogle faces?

Is there a reason why you want the screenshot posted in such a way that you can't enlarge it via clicking on it (I saw you rolled back my edit)?

I thought both syntaxes were equivalent! Why is this not clickable? This is really bad, I used that format on all of my answers across all StackExchange sites until now! I use it because it is much more readable, you do not have to keep scrolling down and back up again when looking at the markdown and then find the spot where you were.

Seems like there is no syntax that makes it clickable without either moving the link away from the text or duplicating the link. So the best option remaining is to write it between the relevant paragraph and the next one.

@Clockwork you might be obsessed with Final Fantasy, Kupo.

@FabianRöling I'm not sure why - might be how the markdown gets rendered into HTML.  But Yea, your first revision made it so I could not click the image to enlarge it.
